# For which a and m does there exist integer b for ab mod m=1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a. a = 5, m = 8
b. a = 29875, m = 75
c. a = 3, m = 79
d. a = 13, m = 91
 I've figured out that A. is correct just by plugging in numbers for b, but I have no idea how to figure it out with the other three.  I tried plugging in numbers but haven't found any that let the equation = 1, but at least one of the three (b-d) do, according to my professor.  How do I go about solving this?

Comment: I assume that you have not yet seen the general criterion. ;) For b., you can change $29875$ to a smaller number. For c., you can notice that $3\times 27 \equiv 81 \equiv 2 \pmod {79}$, and of course $2\times 40 \equiv 80 \equiv 1 \pmod {79}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ \ \exists\,x\!:\ ax\equiv 1\pmod m\iff \exists\,x,y\!:\ ax+my = 1\!\!\overset{\rm\ \  Bezout}\iff \gcd(a,m)=1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Look up the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). There, you will be taught to find a relation between $x$ and $y$ such that $$\mu x+\nu y = 1.$$
Now, say we take modulo $y$, we then get $$\mu x\equiv 1\mod y.$$
What is $x$, $y$, $\mu$ and $\nu$ in your case?